# Solving a second order PDE in canonical form

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have to solve the PDE: $$yu_{xx} + (x + y)u_{xy} + xu_{yy} = 0$$ I've found it's hyperbolic whenever $y\not=x$ and its canonical form is $u_{\phi\psi}=-\frac{1}{\psi}u_\phi$

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to do now.. Can I set $z=u_\phi$ and then treat it as an ODE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's what you have to do:
$$u_{\phi\psi}=-\frac{1}{\psi}u_\phi$$
$$z_{\psi}=-\frac{1}{\psi}z$$
$$\psi z_{\psi}+z=0$$
$$(\psi z)'=0$$
$$\psi z=C_1(\phi)$$
Where $z=u_{\phi}$.
$$\psi u_{\phi}=C_1(\phi)$$
$$u({\psi},\phi)=\dfrac {g(\phi)}{\psi}+f(\psi)$$